# Detect drive addition/removal linux

Tags: c, linux

I have been trying to see if there is a signal I need to handle, but I can't seem to find one.  I need to be able to detect when a drive is inserted/removed from a server from within c code.

Semi-related but probably deserves it's own question:
Is there any way to map a specific drive slot to a device name? For example, the server has 6 locations for harddrives; can I make it such that location 1 is always /dev/sda?

Comment: You might want to look into udev for both of these.

Comment: Will that work internally? I was under the impression that if you made a udev rule, it would execute another program.

Comment: See: http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/libudev/libudev-udev-monitor.html for the libudev way.

Comment: This looks like the kind of thing I've been looking for. Thank you!
I've been stuck on this problem for weeks, just kinda pushed it to the back of my list of problems to solve every time it came up.